# How do I play a sound with 360player (soundmanager2)?

Tags: html5-audio, soundmanager2

I've set up soundmanager:

```
soundManager.setup({
```

And I've created a sound:

```
soundManager.createSound({
```

From the console I also have threeSixtyPlayer:

```
threeSixtyPlayer.init()
threeSixtyPlayer.init(): Found 0 relevant items.
```

So how do I make the 360player play the sound? And how do I detect that it is finished playing so that I can create and play the next one after that?

Answer (score 0):

The docs lack information regarding 360ui but from what I've tried:

HTML code needed:

```
<div id="sm2-container"></div>
<div class="ui360 ui360-vis">
    <a id="song_link" class="sm2_link" href="asfgasg.mp3"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
soundManager.setup({
    url: 'inc/soundmanager/',
    flashVersion: 9,
    useFlashBlock: true,
    onready: function() {
        soundManager.createSound('someSongId_', selectedSong);
    },
    ontimeout: function() {
        // Error msg
    }
});
```

You also need the files (depending on the theme you want):

- flashblock.css
- 360player.css
- 360player-visualization.css
- berniecode-animator.js
- 360-button-vis-play-light.png
- 360-button-vis-pause-light.png

After that there should be a div with a "play" image.

To play you can use soundManager.getSoundById('myId') and chain it with the onfinish event. Example at the doc:

```
soundManager.play('myId',{
    onfinish: function() {
    alert('The sound '+this.id+' finished playing.');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps...